# Context API React Native

Tags: react-native, state, react-context

Hi I'm using Context API in order to be able to access to some data (like the user id). But whenever I try to `console.log()` the value of the state I got undefined.

```
// store/UserProvider.js
import React, { createContext, Component } from "react"; // on importe createContext qui servira à la création d'un ou plusieurs contextes

export const UserContext = createContext({
  id: '',
});

class UserProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    id: '',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default UserProvider;
```

This is where I set the value.

```
<UserContext.Provider value = {{state:this.state.id}}>
   ...
</UserContext.Provider>
```

```
<UserContext.Consumer>
  {(value) => (
   <ScrollView style = {styles.container}>
     {console.log("Context Id: "+ value.id)}
     <View style = {[GlobalInclude.container, { marginTop:32 }]}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={[ styles.button, styles.button1, { marginBottom:32 } ]} onPress = {() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('ModifProfil', {id: value.id})}}>
       <Text style={styles.textBtn}>MODIFIER MON PROFIL</Text>
       <Icon style = {{ }} name="chevron-right" size={18} color="#000" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
   </ScrollView>
</UserContext.Consumer>
```

So the console.log of value sends me undefined, does anybody knows why ? Thanks !

Comment: U've assigned ur `id` to variable `state` inside of an object .......That seems to be the problem to me!

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand I'm new to react, so how can I change that ?

Comment: {{id:this.state.id}} try this!

Comment: In the provider ? I have changed it but still get undefined

Comment: Okay I thought that might be the error! Sorry even I'm pretty new to React-Native